# Lagging audio and video on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, nvidia

Apparently I have absolutely no idea what I'm doing. I'm pretty good at solving problems with Windows usually, but I'm afraid I've made my problem worse with this OS and am at a loss. I'm also having trouble even navigating my way around my system to see what is what.

It all started with slightly slow performance online and off and my machine would sort of freeze up and the screen would "grey out" for a few seconds, then come back. Anything I would try to watch, mainly in Amazon Prime would be severely delayed in video and the audio wouldn't match up. 
It's still doing all of that but seems much worse after me attempting to update my Adobe flash and Nvidia driver, which I don't thing I did right anyway because I can't figure out how to install something after I've downloaded it. I tried using the terminal through blog help suggestions too, but simply have no idea if I'm using the right commands for my system and issues. Please help.

I'm using an older laptop that a friend loaded with Linux and gave to me. 
It is a Latitude E5500 with Intel® Core™2 Duo CPU P8600 @ 2.40GHz × 2 
32 bit. I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 as far as I can tell.

Comment: What's your nVidia card?

Comment: I'm sorry, for some reason I didn't get a notification for the answers to my question, even though I have it set in my preferences to email me ... or maybe I just missed it. I didn't know what kind of graphics was in my machine anyway, and I couldn't figure out how to find the info to check. Having a hard time finding a lot of things. I'm working on learning some basics but this is all very different and more complicated than what I'm used to. Thank you for the response but another user informed me it wasn't even an nVidia card. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Google (checked at three different websites) your Dell Latitude E5500 laptop does not have an Nvidia graphics card in it. You can also check this yourself by opening the terminal and running `lspci -vnnn | grep VGA`. Instead your laptop has the Intel Graphics Media Accelerator 4500MHD graphics processor. Therefore you should uninstall the Nvidia driver, which will revert Ubuntu back to using its default graphics driver. To uninstall the Nvidia driver open the terminal and type:

```
sudo mv /etc/X11/xorg.conf /etc/X11/xorg.conf.nvidia  
sudo apt-get purge nvidia-settings nvidia-current
```

...and then reboot to enable the default driver for your laptop's Intel GMA 4500MHD graphics processor.

Comment: Thank you so much, I had no idea. I was able to run the second command but the first one gave me this response. "mv: cannot stat `/etc/X11/xorg.conf': No such file or directory". 

I wasn't sure how to enter the text so I tried typing the commands separately and together with the same results. 
It is still running pretty choppy but at least the audio and video aren't out of sync at the moment. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Your laptop's hardware specifications look OK, so even installing a lightweight flavor of Ubuntu such as Xubuntu might not give you much of an improvement in performance, in case your video performance issue is being caused by something else. You could try installing VLC from the Ubuntu Software Center and see if that helps. And also try enabling the [YouTube HTML5 Video Player](http://www.youtube.com/html5).

Comment: I have VLC already, but right now the problem is trying to watch video online. It worked fine a few days ago, that's why I'm confused as to why it started acting like this all of a sudden. I hadn't altered anything at that point. I tried deleting cookies and the cache but it didn't help.

Comment: I don't have cable tv so my daughter and I stream many shows online... that's why it's more of an issue than not. I appreciate the feedback and help, and please let me know if you (or anyone else) knows of other things I might try :)

Comment: It's strange, it seems to get worse the longer I'm on the computer in one session. I started watching something about 20 minutes ago and it was streaming almost good, and now it's lagging so badly, it's unwatchable. The computer is slower over all too, as in switching between tabs and the time it takes for content from drop down menus to appear...

Comment: I'm seriously worried that you might have an overheating problem. A friend of mine's got a Dell laptop, and he can't even run it without putting a laptop cooling fan underneath it. You can install Psensor and then you have to configure it in the terminal to check your hardware temperatures; it is an awesome application. If your temperatures are high it might be caused by dustballs in the aluminum cooling block which is an inexpensive, routine computer technician job to fix it.

Comment: Ok, thank you, I will see about that. I actually do already have a cooling fan that is still in the box, so that may work out very well :)

Comment: Doesn't seem to be running hot, and the problem persists. I did find where I could run some tests and got this: graphics/compiz_check - failed - Xlib: extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".  Also, is there a way to update my existing driver? I was always able to do so with Windows without too much problem, but every time I try and download something with Linux, I can't figure out how to install it. My online video streaming used to work fine and just all of a sudden started lagging out of the blue. I found where my firefox flash plugin needed updating and tried to do so with no luck. Thanks.

Comment: The default graphics driver that comes with the Ubuntu install should be good the way it is for your computer. I don't think that trying to update your existing graphics driver would help. Sometimes you can work around a flash streaming problem by deleting the "&feature=youtube_gdata" and "feature=player_embedded&" strings from the YouTube video, and then playing it on YouTube instead of on the website where you found it. Or else by checking in the downloads section of the website where you found the video for an mp4 download, and then streaming the mp4 video online instead.

Comment: @AngiC I didn't have enough space for it in my last comment, so here is the continuation of my last comment. 1) mp4 streaming is often just as fast as flash. 2) There is a button with an arrow in the bottom right-hand corner of the default mp4 video player web browser tab that you can click to get into fullscreen mode without seeing any panels, etc.